# how to set mongoose indexes correctly and test them

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to set 2 indexes for now, perhaps a 3rd but wanted to know how I can test if they are actually working? Do I need to use with mongo shell or is there a way to check using Node.js during development? I also saw an example of the indexes being created in mongoDb Compass. I am using mongoDb Atlas so wondered if I must just set the index in Compass or do I still need to do it in my mongoose schema?

Also, the mongoose docs say you should set autoIndex to false. Is the below then correct?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
  },
});

userSchema.set("autoIndex", false);
userSchema.index({ firstName: 1, lastName: 1 });

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of different questions here, let's see if we can tackle them in order.

> I want to set 2 indexes for now, perhaps a 3rd

This isn't a question from your side, but rather from mine.  What are the indexes that you are considering and what queries will you be running?

The reason I ask is because I only see a single index definition provided in the question (`{ firstName: 1, lastName: 1 }`) and no query. Normally indexes are designed specifically to support the queries, so the first step towards ensuring a successful indexing strategy is to make sure they align appropriately with the anticipated workload.

> how I can test if they are actually working? Do I need to use with mongo shell or is there a way to check using Node.js during development?

There are a few ways to approach this, which include:

- Using [the `explain()` method](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/) to confirm that the `winningPlan` is using the index as expected. This is often done via the MongoDB Shell or via Compass.
- Using the `$indexStats` aggregation stage to confirm that usage counters of the index are incrementing as expected when the application runs.
- Taking a look at some of the tabs in the Atlas UI such as Performance Advisor or the Profiler which may help alert you to unoptimized operations and missing indexes.

> I am using mongoDb Atlas so wondered if I must just set the index in Compass or do I still need to do it in my mongoose schema?

You can use Compass (or the Atlas UI, or the MongoDB Shell) to create your indexes. I would recommend against doing this in the application directly.

> Also, the mongoose docs say you should set autoIndex to false. Is the below then correct?

As noted above, I would go further and remove index creation from the application code altogether. There can be some unintended side effects of making the application directly responsible for index management, which is one of the reasons that Mongoose no longer recommends using the `autoIndex` functionality.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed reply. To answer your question, I would be using an equality `.find` where the user could enter a first name or last name for example. The code in my question is just for the mongoose schema and no queries are run in there. The query code will run in my controller for the relevant API endpoint. Just to make sure I understand your last few points, are you saying I should remove any index code from the mongoose schema and rather create the indexes in Compass? I would prefer to do that actually, so I hope that is what you are saying :)

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I'm suggesting (about where/when to create indexes). Based on this additional comment where you would be searching for "_first name or last name_", you may find [this information about `$or` with indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#-or-clauses-and-indexes) useful

Comment: Oh, sorry. Forgot to ask one thing. Will this still work if I set the index in Compass if there are already a lot of records in the db or does it only work for any new entries add to the db?

Comment: I don't know exactly what your question is, but I'm pretty sure that the answer is "yes" regardless. When you ask if "this" will still work, what is "this"?  Regardless, you can find details about building indexes on existing collections [here in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-creation/)

Comment: Sorry, what I meant by 'this' is creating the indexes in Compass. So, if I have loads of data in the database already, will the indexing still work with existing data or only new data.

Comment: Of course! One component of databases is that they must always return correct results, so MongoDB will index existing data and won't begin using the index until it is ready to satisfy queries correctly. The biggest concern about creating indexes on existing production systems and their data are really around the operational impact of the index creation itself. The link in my previous comment speaks more to that. In any case, the behavior of the database does not change based on what client is used to create the index.